# Understanding 5 consecutive "that"s in this sentence

Tags: relative-clauses, syntactic-analysis, subordinate-clauses

(This sentence was told as an entertainment by my English teacher 8 years ago.) She presented us with the following sentence:

> She said that that that that that he said was wrong.

I had a bit of trouble trying to figure out what each *that* means, and am still having a bit of trouble even now.

After killing my brain for hours on this, I worked this out:

- There are only 3 predicate verbs in the sentence, so there should be exactly 2 *that*'s that start a subclause
- No two consecutive *that*'s can have a solid meaning, or it's a grammar error
- Given the above two points, the second and the fourth *that*'s are starts of two subclauses, and the first, the third and the last *that*s have a solid meaning.
- The first *that* and the whole subclause led by the second *that* are appositive. Similarly, the third *that* and the subclause led by the fourth *that* are appositive.

The sentence now looks like this:

```
She said *that* that *that* that *that* he said was wrong.
|             |      |           |            |         |
|             |      | inner - 1 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~         |
|             |    2 ~~~~~~.....................~~~~~~~~~
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 3 - outer
```

It's then that problems arise. I can't understand why the last *that* is fine here. If the above ideas are correct, then the third *that* is the object of the innermost subclause (marked as 1), and the last *that* doesn't serve as any structural element in that clause.

What's the role of the last *that* in the innermost subclause? Or did I interpret the sentence wrongly?

Comment: dude, i think you may have it wrong, it's 4x thats  :O

Comment: in your example, the thing said originally was "that that".  That's not "impossible" but ... I mean you could just put anything in there.  ("She said that that 'that that that thattidy that' that he said was wrong." for example.)

Comment: OK, I can see how it works with five thats.  A "that that" is a thing  :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's meant to be interpreted this way:

> She said that that *"that that"* that he said was wrong.

(So, "that that" often appears in English; it is tricky to use correctly. Some student, John, used a "that that".  John did so badly. Hence: the teacher said that that "that that" that John used was wrong.)

Once you emphasize the *"that that"* originally spoken item, it is fairly clear.

So just TBC, your diagram is incorrect and not solvable: the two thats I show grouped, are grouped.

---

(As mentioned in a comment, for me it makes more sense when the "thing" in italics is just "that".  That's the way I've usually heard it posed.  But yes, a *that that* is enough of a thing that you can, uh, make it the thing in the trick sentence!)